# После авторизации в поле вставляется почта и пароль

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

Делаю форму на jquery, которая делает post запрос после изменения поля с почтой, но браузер сам вставляем почту по всей видимости их сессии и пароль.
Как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило?

```
$("#email").focusout(function () {
    if ($("#email").val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/admin/check_email",
        data: JSON.stringify({"email": $("#email").val()}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
           //do something
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {

            //do something else
        }
        });
    }
        });
```

сама форма

```
 <form action="{{ url_for('admin.signup') }}" method="POST" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                 <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="first_name">Имя</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="uname" placeholder="Имя">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="last_name">Фамилия</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" id="" placeholder="Фамилия">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user_email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-error="Email написан не правильно" required>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="password">Пароль</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user_password" id="password" placeholder="Пароль">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Проблема в том, когда я загружаю страницу, скрипт видит,что поле не пустое и начинает делать post запрос. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы запретить браузеру заполнять атоматически поля, поставьте аттрибут `autocomplete`:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Его можно навесить как на всю форму:

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
[…]
</form>
```

так на какой-то элемент в частности:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
```